# What do they drink in Japan for breakfast, lunch and dinner?

Tags: japan, food-and-drink, local-cuisine

What do Japanese drink for daily meals (breakfast, lunch and dinner)? I need to know.

Comment: If you are catering for Japanese people, rather than choosing what you are going to drink, would the cooking stack exchange be a better fit?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it doesn't clearly demonstrate how it is related to travel.

Answer (score 3):

Green tea is the most common, and drunk to all meals; restaurants will often serve it complimentary with [Oolong tea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oolong_tea) as a premium alternative. Soda drinks are also popular, and for dinner, beer is very common.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of things, but traditionally and still most commonly green tea.